# insert value and select from column from and to the same table

Tags: select, insert

My_Table (Contains Columns A & B).
I need to Check Column A and if it does not equal a designated fixed value Add a new record using the designated fixed Value for Column A and existing Column B Value for Column B.

Is there way to combine VALUES & SELECT into a INSERT Statement?
Temp Table?
How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What language is this for? SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Your question's a bit unclear, but I *think* this should do it

```
INSERT INTO My_Table (A, B)
(SELECT "DESIGNATED_VALUE", B FROM My_Table WHERE A <> "DESIGNATED_VALUE")
```